# Find Text and add class if value is less than or equals to

Tags: jquery

i want to add a class to a `<tr>` in my table if its value is less than or equals to `40 %`
i'm pretty sure this can be done using jQuery. but i can't make this work.

What i've already tried.

**Method #1**

```
var $rows = $('#report-card table tr');
$rows.each(function(i, item) {
    $this = $(item);
    if ($this.text()) <= '40 %' ) {
        $this.addClass('fail');
    }

});
```

**Method #2**

```
$('#report-card table tr').each(function(){
  if ($.trim($(this).text()) <= '40 %') {
    $(this).addClass("fail");
  }
});
```

Here is the testing JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XkCLe/1/

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#report-card table tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
    var txt = $(this).find("td:last").text();
    txt = txt.substr(0, txt.length - 2);
    txt = parseInt(txt);
    if (txt <= 40) {
        $(this).addClass("fail");
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XkCLe/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your fiddle, you should do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#report-card table tr').each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).find('td:last').text()) <= '40 %') {
           $(this).addClass("fail");
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: thank you Ramesh, i've tried this code but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this:

```
$this = $(item);  //<----------wrong selector
if ($this.text()) <= '40 %' ) { //<-------here extra ')' after .text()
    $this.addClass('fail');
}
```

to this:

```
$this = $(item).find('td:last');
if ($this.text() <= '40 %' ) {
    $this.closest('tr').find('td').addClass('fail'); // <---update to this
}
```

and in your fiddle you have not selected the jquery library from the left top side bar from this section: **Frameworks & Extensions**

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XkCLe/8/)

Comment: Thank you Jai for pointing out my errors, you can see i'm a newbie :) so thanks alot for your help

Comment: Oh great! this helped you.